# Amazon SES email security

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, spf, dkim

I have a question about the security of the emails in the amazon ses.
According to their docs and verification here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication-spf.html
and 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-authentication-dmarc.html

They advise to publish the record to consisting of this:

"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"

However, doesnt that make Your domain to be accessible for all of the accounts using the AWS SES? Isnt this a bit of a security issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This validates that emails are allowed to be sent from SES. Its primarily you acknowledging that Amazon is allowed to send emails on your behalf.

Additionally a username/password via SMTP or IAM credentials via AWS api are used to send the email, these are the validation step from the AWS perspective.

See more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: Yes, so everyone using Amazon can sent email from my own domain, am I right?

Comment: No, you also create a verification record that AWS asks you to set to a specific value. Unless someone else’s AWS account also asked for that random value in the text record at the same time as you there’s no way for them to generate credentials, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-txt-records.html

Comment: Yes, however the check on my server is based on the domain amazonses.com, not on this verification record value. Am I right?

Comment: Hi, the spf record is just one part. You also get credentials you use to send the email. Without those the email cannot be sent

Comment: I am still not quite getting this. I am getting credentials to send the email, that's right. And I can configure for instance the change in the MAIL FROM on my own(however as I have checked it still needs me to allow all of the emails from amazonses). However, everyone gets their own credentials. For instance - lets say company A has configured their domain, and company B. Both allowing all of the emails to be sent from amazonses. Does this mean that company A can in some point send an email with the domain from company B? They have allowed emails to be sent from amazonses...

Comment: No, so each AWS account that generate these credential needs to validate via a TXT verification record (seperate from SPF) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-txt-records.html. The value is different for each AWS account

Comment: Yes, but where will the error occur on the situation discribed above? I assume that the request goes from the SES of the B company to the mailbox of the A company. A company checks that request comes from the valid spf source(amazonses) and it goes through. What does those TXT records validate on our mailbox?

Comment: That TXT record validates in AWS console to grant permission to generate credentials that can be used to send the emails. Its basically proving you own the domain

Comment: So when we try the described situation - the checks will not go through the SES right? And it will be rejected before trying to reach a mailbox A right?

Comment: SES won't even try sending as it will not have valid credentials, correct :)

Comment: Proving you own the domain does not prevent a malicious user sending email AS you, if they have your smtp credentials. OP is correct, it is possible for a malicious user to send email as your domain name through AWS, and happens all the time.